# Its is a program to print host name from IP but Its not printing HostName

Tags: java, dns

```
package networking;
import java.net.*;
public class HostIpAddess {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("204.29.207.217");
            System.out.println("IP Name:"+address.getHostName());
        }catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the program deliver the IP address and not the result of the reverse DNS lookup?

Comment: What is it doing? Throwning an exception? What does it say? Else what does it print?

Comment: I'm seeing two potential errors. 1) The IP is disconnected. 2) The IP doesn't exist.

Comment: This Program is running It is printing IP address.....bt it should print Host name.

Comment: You might also need to `import java.lang.*;` and `import java.util.*;`

Comment: @fireshadow52  the `lang` package never needs to be imported.  The code does not use any of the classes of the `util` package.

Comment: @fireshadow52: the secod option. If an IP is _disconnected_ (?) it does not affect DNS queries.

Comment: @Srikjanth: since the IP does not have a reverse DNS `getByName` returns the IP address. The OP supposed that an `UnknownHostException` should be thrown if the IP cannot be resolved (but this is not the case).

Answer (score 3):

The IP address 204.29.207.217 does not have a PTR record.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

Comment: If you run the code with IP 137.254.16.66, it will return www.java.com. Conclusion: Your code is ok. The ip you test it with does not have a PTR record.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working: the problem is that `InetAddress.getByName` returns the host name only

- if it exists (i.e., the reverse lookup return an host name)
- if the JVM is able to perform the reverse lookup (from the documentation "[...]If the operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of the IP address[...]"

In your case a reverse DNS lookup of the given IP address does not return a result:

```
$ host 204.29.207.217
Host 217.207.29.204.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

You can perform test lookups at http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=204.29.207.217&cat=all&all=no

Answer (score 0):

By reading Java API documentation (Have you read it?) I would suggest try using `getCanonicalHostName()`.

Comment: Since the IP does not have an host name `getCanonicalHostName()` will behave exactly as `getHostName()`. As documented it will return a textual representation of the IP address.